# Rank-$2$ $\Bbb Z$-module invariant under action of root of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Assume $\epsilon =e^{2\pi i /n}$ -some root of unity. For which $n$ it is possible to find $x=re^{i\phi} \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\epsilon (\mathbb{Z} + re^{i \phi}\mathbb{Z}) \subset (\mathbb{Z} + re^{i \phi}\mathbb{Z}) $?

But any comments, as usual , will be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Have you found many values of $n$ for which this works? The ones I can think of are all relatively small. Geometrically this is about plane lattices stable under a rotation of finite order, and I think the usual suspects give all of them. Need to recall the argument...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: thank you for response, i will pay attention to geometrical side also

Answer (score 2):

You're asking for two-dimensional $\Bbb Z$-lattices which have some rotational symmetry. Ultimately you should be able to see that $r=1$ or else $\epsilon\not\in \Bbb Z + x\Bbb Z$. In fact in this case it must be that we can choose $\phi$ generated by $\epsilon$. But your question is actually even simpler than that, since you want this to be closed under the $\Bbb Z[\epsilon]$ action, you need that your module is actually a rank-2 module over $\Bbb Z$, which means it's just going to be $\Bbb Z[i]$ or $\Bbb Z[\omega]$ where here $\omega$ is a primitive third root of 1, since these are the only degree $2$ roots of unity aside from the sixth roots of unity, but we know that $-\omega$ is such a root, so it's already within $\Bbb Z[\omega]$. This can be seen in a myriad of ways, but I think the simplest is just to note that the degree of a root of unity is $\phi(n)\ge \sqrt{n/2}$.

Comment: Please excuse the picky correction, but the sixth roots of unity also are quadratic over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Lubin of course you are right. Enough years in number theory to not bother telling an odd and twice an odd apart in cyclotomy and not enough to remember they still matter!

Comment: @AdamHughes, can you give some comments on your observation that  $\phi$ can be chosen as generated by $\epsilon$ ($r=1$ is trivial, and other explanations are clear). You say, that from $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \epsilon  \subset \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} e^{i\phi}$ it follows that they are equal, am i right? Thank you)

Comment: @Anna if that were the case then your rank would be off, remember you have a very strong assumption that this is rank $2$ as a $\Bbb Z$-module:  if $e^{i\phi}$ is not a root of unity, then $1, \epsilon, e^{i\phi}$ are all linearly independent over $\Bbb Z$, hence the rank is at least 3.

Comment: @AdamHughes is there a simple reason for why $\epsilon$ can not be expressed as $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combination of $1,e^{i\phi}$ in the case $e^{i\phi}$, $\epsilon$ doesn't coincide?

Comment: @Anna Linear independence of such things is classical, but one easy way to see is that $a+b\epsilon$ as a transformation of the plane is affine, it rotates, dilates, then translates, whereas $e^{i\phi}$ is a pure rotation. But then in order for $a+b\epsilon = e^{i\phi}$, i.e. linear dependence, we'd need that these induce the same isometry, but this is only possible if it fixes $0$, i.e. there is no translation, $a=0$, and does not dilate, i.e. $b=1$, hence $\epsilon = e^{i\phi}$ in the case there is a dependence.

Comment: @AdamHughes, thank you for very detailed answer

Comment: @Anna glad to help. Keep in mind you should still try and work out the details to be sure you understand things completely, and best of luck with your studies

Comment: @AdamHughes, i will, thank you so much! But I'd like to make a small remark to your answer: $e^{-4\pi i/3}=1+ e^{2\pi i/3}$, and therefore your argument might seem a bit incomplete.

Comment: @Anna that is correct, and part of why I said you should try and work out the details yourself. Working out the associated lemmata for the main result is good practice. :)

Comment: @Anna and here's a more algebraic way:  if $e^{i\phi}$ is not a root of unity, then it will generate an infinite degree extension of $\Bbb Q$ in particular $\Bbb Z[e^{i\phi}]$ is not a finite rank $\Bbb Z$-module. SImilarly if it is a root of unity what can you conclude?

Comment: @AdamHughes, $\mathbb{Z}[a+b\epsilon]=\mathbb{Z}[\epsilon]$ is f.g. $\mathbb{Z}$-module, with rank less than degree of root unit.

Comment: @AdamHughes,but  roots of unity are not the only algebraic integers with the value of norm equals to $1$, so that $\mathbb{Z}[e^{i\phi}]$ is not that simple..

Comment: @Anna but they are for rank $2$, you have to keep that in mind, that's the most essential part of this question start to finish. The key to addressing this problem is seeing all the info **together** not just one aspect at a time.

Comment: @AdamHughes, "one aspect at a time" -- is definitely for me today! But $\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}[e^{i\phi}]$ need not to coincide with $\mathbb{Z}[e^{i\phi}]$ in my question! It only should be $\epsilon$-invariant. Thank you again for very long and useful discussion!